# How to run a stored procedure in a loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table for `"Departments" (ID,deptID)`

```
ID  parentdeptID  
2 null  
3 null  
7 2  
8 2  
9 3
```

and a second table `"Filter"` contains IDs only

```
ID  
2  
9
```

and a stored procedure with only input prameter `@deptID` and the output is a result from joining some of tables depending on the input ID

my question is: a way read from table "Filter" and gets IDs, and for each ID get its childs if it has
in our example:

`2,7,8,9 (2,9  from "Filter" and 7,8 from "Departments" as childs of 2)`

and then for each one of this 4 IDs excute the stored procedure by ID

This is the overview, if any one has a better way without using stored procedure he is welcome

Comment: It's rather hard to say whether it's possible to do what you want without using a stored procedure when you haven't told us what the stored procedure does.

Comment: Dear 'Mark Byers', thanks for feedback, I edited my question, I hope it is clear now

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your model too well, but here's how you can do a loop and execute a stored procedure inside of it:

**Edit** I think I understand your question a little better now.

```
declare @filterId int
declare @deptId int

select @filterId = min(ID) from Filter
while @filterId is not null
   begin
      -- run the stored procedure for the main filter ID
      exec procedureName @filterId

      -- run the SP for the related IDs in Department table
      select @deptId = min(ID) from Departments where parentdeptID = @filterID
      while @deptId is not null
         begin
            exec procedureName @deptId
            select @deptId = min(ID) from Departments where ID > @deptId and parentdeptID = @filterID
         end

      select @filterId = ID from Filter where ID > @filterId
   end
```

Hopefully this gets you started.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want without the stored procedure you should join the DeptID's with the query inside the stored procedure.

Assume that your SP does a `select DeptID, DeptInfo from @SomeOtherTableWithData where DeptiID = @DeptID`.

Here is sample code with your tables that replaces the stored procedure with a join instead.

```
-- Setup sample data
declare @Departments table (DeptID int, ParentDeptID int)
declare @Filter table (DeptID int)
declare @SomeOtherTableWithData table (DeptID int, DeptInfo varchar(50))

insert into @Departments values (2, null)  
insert into @Departments values (3, null)  
insert into @Departments values (7, 2)  
insert into @Departments values (8, 2)  
insert into @Departments values (9, 3) 

insert into @Filter values(2)
insert into @Filter values(9)

insert into @SomeOtherTableWithData values (2, 'Info DeptID 2')
insert into @SomeOtherTableWithData values (3, 'Info DeptID 3')
insert into @SomeOtherTableWithData values (7, 'Info DeptID 7')
insert into @SomeOtherTableWithData values (8, 'Info DeptID 8')
insert into @SomeOtherTableWithData values (9, 'Info DeptID 9')

-- Get the DeptID's into temporary table #DeptIDs
select D.DeptID  -- Parents
into #DeptIDs 
from @Departments as D
    inner join @Filter as F
        on D.DeptID = F.DeptID
union
select D.DeptID  -- Children
from @Departments as D
    inner join @Filter as F
        on D.ParentDeptID = F.DeptID

-- Use #DeptID in a join with the query in the stored procedure
select S.DeptID, S.DeptInfo
from #DeptIds as D
    inner join @SomeOtherTableWithData as S
        on D.DeptID = S.DeptID

-- Drop the temporary table
drop table #DeptIDs
```

The result is

```
DeptID  DeptInfo
2   Info DeptID 2
7   Info DeptID 7
8   Info DeptID 8
9   Info DeptID 9
```

You can use a sub-query instead of the temporary table if you want just one SQL statement.